# excel command to search across row for "STATUS" and if it's found return text in mid-string

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
j                 k           l         m               n         o           p    q   r   s      
 t
result1           result2     result3   result4         result5   result6                  statustypes  60Present
0:0STATUS_OK_12   1.1USB_Y_3  f.txt60   1.2STATUS_bad_1 3USB_c_4  2STATUS_c_k ...          OK,bad       yes 
0:0STATUS_bad_12   1.1USB_z_3  f.txt601 1.2STATUS_bad_1 3USB_c_4  2STATUS_c_k ...          OK,bad       yes
..
```

How would I find if the row contains "STATUS" and if it does, return what comes between the _ after "STATUS", like I show in column r? Like Return Ok or bad?

I was thinking something like what I am doing for column t to see if it contains 60, but this is different because I'd need to concatenate the mid result in one column.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H6:R6,"*60*"),"YES","NO")
```

I'm having trouble searching for this, but the closest I found was [search within text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298913/search-for-text-within-the-text-in-a-cell-and-return-that-cell-if-found), or [range contains text](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-if-range-of-cells-contains-specific-text/).

That would be great if you can help.

UPDATE:
I was noticing that my STATUS line looks like this:
STATUS_1200_OK or STATUS_1250_OK.  How do I parse the OK out?

Comment: If you have Excel 2019+ you can use [TextJoin If](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Answer (score 0):

This formula will extract the data you're looking for (according to your description but not to your example*) from cell J2:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(J2,FIND("_",J2,FIND("STATUS_",J2)+7)-1),FIND("STATUS_",J2)+7,999),"")
```

You can then drag it to cover all your data. You can then combine the results and obtain the final data.

*in your example you missed the two `c` from the `result6` column; also `result1` column second row contains `bad` and not `OK`. Moreover: are you sure that `f.txt601` (`result3` column second row) counts for a positive 60? Are 60 or 601 the same for your endevour?

---

**EDIT: new formula as requested in comments**

This formula shall check if the string contains the `STATUS_` and then extract the part of the string after the second `_` to the end of the string itself:

```
=IFERROR(MID(MID(J2,FIND("STATUS_",J2)+7,999),FIND("_",MID(J2,FIND("STATUS_",J2)+7,999))+1,999),"")
```

Comment: I'm note entirely sure.  I put the formula in the statustype column, and I know the first row has statuses (see top spreadsheet row I show), but how would it search across the row to get all of them?

Comment: and can you explain what the -1, 999, and 7's are in the formula? What if I have random numbers after STATUS_ , like STATUS_6901_OK, or STATUS_6902_OK?

Comment: You have to drag the formula to cover the whole results. 6 results will need 6 columns. You can then combine the result with a formula using `CONCATENATE` or `&` and maybe some extra perks like `&", "&`. It might be possible to create a formula that will return the final result in just one cell, but it will most likely be quite heavy.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try.  But also, what if I want to get more characters after STATUS_ ?

Comment: The formula is basically cutting the original string as needed. In order to do that, it has to find the position of `STATUS_` and the first `_` following it. The function `FIND` determines where those strings are in the source string, but it returns the position of the first character of said strings (therefore `S` and `_`). So we have to work on said data to aim at the string we are looking for. The -1 is to move the aim 1 character back. The 7 is to move it foward (because `STATUS_` has a lenght of 7). 999 is there because the `MID` function needs a lenght and 999 will cover any string.

Comment: If there is a logic to identify how many more characters to extract, we might be able to do so. You asked for those between `STATUS_` and its next `_`. If you need a different result, you have to ask for something different.

Comment: I added Update to show that I am asking for STATUS_1200_OK or STATUs_1250_OK, parse the ok out.

Comment: Are those the complete strings? So basically you need to check if the string contains the `STATUS_` and then extract the part of the string after the second `_` to the end of the string itself?

Comment: yes, I need to extract the string after the second _

Comment: Added the new formula to the answer. Test it and send feedback.

Comment: I wound up using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576876/excel-textjoin-filtered-results-from-different-sheet/72579440#72579440