# Excel textjoin filtered results from different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a tab, List_State_6.10.2022 that looks like this:

```
     A                    G         ...  J          ...  S
1    Device    Org   ...  component ...  Display    ...  Comp+Display
     ABC123    co    ...  part1     ...  Not Found  ...  part1+Not Found
     ABC234    co    ...   part2    ...  ok         ...  part2+ok
     ABC123    co    ...   part3    ...  ok         ...  part3+ok
```

I have a FinalResult tab that is trying to do multiple lookups in this tab above to find states, and appending each one found for same device number into the same cell for w2.

w2 should show: `part1+Not Found;part3+ok`

I got a working solution for Office365 in the following topic, however I'm using Excel 2016 and need a solution for that version.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023831/excel-lookup-index-that-can-return-multiple-results)

Edit: removed questions about Excel versions.

Comment: what is `_xlfn.LET` and `_xlfn._xlws.FILTER`?

Comment: I can't remember.  I had posted a question a while ago and someone suggested this answer.  I'm not clear about the commands. I can't find my old question.  Probably Oct 25-December timeframe.

Comment: Let and Filter do not work in 2016, my guess is that in some time there was a copy/paste from one workbook to the other and Excel tried to make sense of it.  But that is why you have the error.

Comment: If you open a file that was designed with Office 365 functions such as `LET` or `FILTER` and your Excel version doesn't support those functions, it'll show like that.

Comment: @ScottCraner any idea how to fix it and use excel 2016? Maybe excel was updated to 2016 since I did this.

Comment: No, because TEXTJOIN, FILTER, and LET do not exist in 2016.  and it would have been a downgrade from Office 365 to 2016.  It would most likely take vba to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe if you used a web version of Excel it had the functionalities?

Comment: @P.b any idea how to do this in excel 2016? I'm not sure why I used to use 365 functions, but I don't have 365.

Comment: I didn't use a web version of excel before. How do I do this in 2016 version?

Comment: I suggest opening a new post tagging [excel-formula] & [Excel 2016] with sample data and expected result and explanation.

Comment: I figured out what to do.  The problem was that the file used to be in my documents folder under one drive.  I moved it to a share drive to make it accessible to other people and organize.  One drive used office 365.  The share drive doesn't.  I'm installing office 365 on my computer and it should use the 365 formulas now.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I decided it's easiest to get office 365 installed. But when I open the document the formula still doesn't work.  Any ideas? I tried opening the old spreadsheet with 365 and when I drag the formula it fills with #name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=TEXTJOIN(";",1,REPT(List_State_6.10.2022!$S:$S,List_State_6.10.2022!$A:$A=$A2))`

This would work on older Excel version.

The `REPT` looks for each value in `List_State_6.10.2022!$S:$S` where the value in `List_State_6.10.2022!$A:$A` equals the value of `$A2` (being the Device in the FinalResult tab). If it doesn't equal it will give a blank value. Textjoin removes the blank values and adds the delimiter in case there are multiple returns.

PS
Unsure if the formula requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.
unable to test this.

Comment: This formula seems to be working.  Thanks a lot! :)